# Sorting images in tile layout

Tags: jquery, tile

I need to be able to sort images (of different sizes) in a container div. They must be "fitted" in a tile layout style, like Windows metro.

I know there are some really good solutions out there like Isotope for jQuery (https://github.com/desandro/isotope) but I really need the most basic functionality, i.e. be able to "tile" images together, nothing more.

How is this tiling done? Is there a super simple example anywhere?

Thankful for all input!